# flutter will pop scope not working in iOS

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

If I use will_pop_scope in my flutter code then it will be run perfectly for android but it not working in iOS. Any other third party packages or gesture swipes are also not working.

> If anyone showing this post from flutter community then please help me out from this problem and
> please fix this issue from google devs or framework flutter insider devs

Answer (score 0):

Put this as your top-level widget, possibly inside the build function:

```
bool canNavigateBack = true;//This should come from a Stream/bloc/etc.


return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () {
          if (Platform.isAndroid) {
            if (canNavigateBack) {
              //Navigate back actions
            } else {
              //Show exit dialog, etc.
            }
          }
          return Future.value(false);
        },
        child: Platform.isIOS
            ? GestureDetector(
                onHorizontalDragEnd: (details) {
                  if (details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx > 50) {
                    if (canNavigateBack) {
                      //Navigate back actions
                    } else {
                      //Show exit dialog, etc.
                    }
                  }
                },
                child: _anotherWidget())
            : _anotherWidget(),
      );
```